# How to refresh all pods using spring config server as soon as properties are pushed to git repository using a web hook

Tags: spring-cloud

I am using the spring config server using the git backend as a property repository. I have deployed my application using k8s pods and there are multiple pods of my application.
How do I make sure upon pushing new properties to bitbucket, all pods get refreshed?

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for a proper answer, but that is what spring cloud bus, combined with spring cloud config monitor was built for

Comment: @amit-kumar have you found/made a solution w/o 3d party system? I'd prefer the same as it's not worth sometimes bringing an infra service just for the refresh config.

It makes sense to call from the master pod all the others

Comment: yeah @ArtemPtushkin, I found a solution that is like this. I created a webhook on bitbucket which calls an API in the config server when new props are checked in. The API in config-server is calling /actuator/refresh for all pods in async way.